# Prolog - identify sublists of variables

Tags: list, prolog

I have an assignment in which I must accomplish the following - given a list such as:

`List = [_, _, $, _, _, _, _, $, _, $].`

I have to write a predicate `pred/2` with `pred(List, Sub)` such that it is `true` if and only if `Sub` is a sublist of size >= 2 with no adjacent variables in which none of the members is a `$`. Examples:

`List = [X, Y, $, P, Q, R, S, $, A, $], pred(List, [X, Y])` should succeed.

`List = [X, Y, $, P, Q, R, S, $, A, $], pred(List, [P, Q, R])` should not succeed because `S` is adjacent to `P, Q, R`.

`List = [X, Y, $, P, Q, R, S, $, A, $], pred(List, [P, Q, R, S])` should succeed.

`List = [X, Y, $, P, Q, R, S, $, A, $], pred(List, [A, $])` should not succeed because it includes a `$`.

I have written the following code, which according to a bit of testing does that I want:

```
pred(List, Sub) :- pred(List, Sub, []).
pred([], Sub, Sub) :- length(Sub, Len),
                             Len >= 2.
pred([H|T], Sub, Aux) :- H \== $, !,
                                  append(Aux, [H], New), 
                                  pred(T, Sub, New).
pred([$|_], Sub, Sub):- length(Sub, Len), Len >= 2.
pred([$|T], Sub, _) :- pred(T, Sub, []).
```

However, I feel like this solution is janky. While I am aware StackOverflow is, in general, for *things that people can't do*, I really feel like I've come up with a rather complicated solution to a simple problem and would like to know of a better way to accomplish what I want.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't think in terms of "should evaluate to true" or "should evaluate to false". Think in terms of will succeed or will fail.

Comment: That's good advice. Imperative programming habits are hard to glue off.

Comment: You do know that `[_, _, $, _, _, _, _, $, _, $]` is a list of anonymous variables with an occassional `$`? It's not a list of non-variables.

Comment: And when you write `List = [X, Y, $, P, Q, R, S, $, A, $], pred(List, [X, Y])` are intending to use variables or should have you written it with atoms like `List = [x, y, $, p, q, r, s, $, a, $], pred(List, [x, y])`?

Comment: I did intend to use variables. Apologies for the mess, I think the edits cleared up the mistakes you mentioned.

Comment: Your code example appears that you intended atoms.

Comment: @Enigmativity I did intend variables. Thank you for fixing my question :)

Comment: So, just confirming for one last time - if I did `List = [X, Y, $, P, Q, R, S, $, A, $], pred(List, [G,H])` then your code should succeed because the `G` unifies with `X` and `H` with `Y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

append/2 is an handy predicate from library(lists). It allows an easier implementation of the requirements:

```erlang
pred(L, S) :-
    append([X, S, Y], L),
    length(S, C), C >= 2,
    maplist(\==($), S),
    ( X = [] ; last(X, X_), X_ == $ ),
    ( Y = [] ; Y = [Y_|_], Y_ == $ ).
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you :)